# Passing variable in jQuery through bind doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery

Here's my code that does work:

```
function mouseOver()
{
    $(".beaver").fadeIn(100);

}

function mouseOut()
{
    $(".beaver").fadeOut(100);
}

$("#group_beaver").bind('mouseenter', mouseOver).bind('mouseleave', mouseOut);
```

But why doesn't this work?

```
function mouseOver(variable)
{
    $(variable).fadeIn(100);

}

function mouseOut(variable)
{
    $(variable).fadeOut(100);
}

$("#group_beaver").bind('mouseenter', mouseOver('.beaver')).bind('mouseleave', mouseOut('.beaver'));
```

Comment: I am a Canadian, but it's not that kind of beaver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct; you're calling `mouseOver` and expecting it to return a function to be bound to the event. To make it actually do that, though, you can use this code:

```
function mouseOver(variable) {
    return function() {
        $(variable).fadeIn(100);
    };
}
function mouseOut(variable) {
    return function() {
        $(variable).fadeOut(100);
    };
}
```

Comment: Awesome. You just saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as an answer by clicking the little check on the side of the answer.

Comment: +1 - That's clever. I figured you would have to call the function from within the handler. Didn't think of returning a function. Even remains useful as a callable function with `mouseOver('.beaver')();`. Learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

icktoofay's technique is called a closure. There's an excruciatingly comprehensive discussion of closures [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ArL0MNJsWwcJ:www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/+javascript+closure). I find them super useful for scheduling events with window.setTimeout(). They basically allow you to load up a function object with preconditions and then evaluate it with no arguments. Pretty nifty.

However for all their novelty closures can usually be avoided. For instance, if `.beaver`'s are children of `#group_beaver` you would be better off with something like

```
function mouseOver()
{
    $(this).children().fadeIn(100);
}
```

In event handlers jQuery makes sure that `this` always refers to the element that triggered the event, so you've basically got an argument for free. Given the simplicity of your example I'm guessing a closure is not necessary.

You could also do:

```
$('group_beaver').mouseenter(function() {
    $(variable).fadeIn(100);
});
```

Which is really just a closure in disguise. Its the same as writing:

```
function mouseOver(variable) {
    return function() {
        $(variable).fadeIn(100);
    }
};

$('#group_beaver').mouseenter(mouseOver('.beaver'));
```

Comment: Could be wrong here, but I think you are wrong. If you are inside a loop and calling this then `variable` will always be the last set value. By having a function that returns a function that uses a parameter variable it creates its own context and retains each `variable` value instead of the last set value. Did I make sense? :s

Comment: Hmm, you are correct. `variable` would have its value set when `mouseOver()` is called, rather than using the value from the original context as it exists when `mouseenter` fires.

Comment: The second to last code block is still correct though, and IMHO better than icktoofay's ;)